# How to get validation events with JaXB?

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

I try to get validation message in variable with Jaxb.
Try example from here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

My code:

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.piyush");
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new File("D:/liferay-develop/workspace/cat_test/v1/STD_MP.xsd")));
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
ValidationEventCollector validationCollector= new ValidationEventCollector();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setEventHandler( validationCollector );
STDMP ts = (STDMP)jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml_gkuzu);
if(validationCollector.hasEvents())
{
    for(ValidationEvent event:validationCollector.getEvents())
    {
        String msg = event.getMessage();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your link points to an api that does not contain setSchema() . You should better link to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should help:

**JAXB2ValidationEventCollector**

`ValidationEventCollector` came from [JAXB 1 (JSR-31)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=031) and doesn't appear to support the changes we made to validation in [JAXB 2 (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) very well.  You can solve this issue by creating a subclass of `ValidationEventHandler` like the following.

```
package forum12295028;

import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.util.ValidationEventCollector;

class JAXB2ValidationEventCollector extends ValidationEventCollector {

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        super.handleEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

The following example can be used to prove that everything works

**Customer**

```
package forum12295028;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = 
        new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
package forum12295028;

public class PhoneNumber {

}
```

**customer.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2"/>
             </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="phone-number">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
   <name>Jane Doe</name>
   <phone-number/>
   <phone-number/>
   <phone-number/>
</customer>
```

**Demo**

```
package forum12295028;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.util.ValidationEventCollector;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("src/forum12295028/customer.xsd")); 

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        ValidationEventCollector validationCollector = new JAXB2ValidationEventCollector();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(validationCollector);

        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("src/forum12295028/input.xml"));

        if(validationCollector.hasEvents())
        {
            for(ValidationEvent event:validationCollector.getEvents())
            {
                String msg = event.getMessage();
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'Jane Doe' with length = '8' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '5' for type 'stringMaxSize5'.
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Jane Doe' of element 'name' is not valid.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-number'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Comment: This solution works. But it really seems like a bug in ValidationEventCollector.

Comment: @JérômeRadix - Agreed, this is one class that didn't transition well from JAXB 1 to JAXB 2.  It's also a class that isn't used very often.

Comment: This doesn't work with `JaxBeanInfo.invokeUnmarshallCallback` from rt.jar. I have to add jaxb-impl to classpath

Comment: (My beans have `afterUnmarshal()` callbacks for additional validation).