# Validating xml. Get the element name that throws cvc-enumeration-valid

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

Good Morning to everyone!

I am validating an xml against an xsd in this way:

```
ValidationEventCollector vec;
    URL xsdUrl;
    Schema schema;
    FicheroIntercambio fichero;

    vec = new ValidationEventCollector();
    try{
        xsdUrl = FicheroIntercambio.class.getResource("xsd/file.xsd");
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schema = sf.newSchema(xsdUrl);
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("file.dto");
        unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(vec);
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(peticion.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        fichero = (FicheroIntercambio)unmarshaller.unmarshal(bais);
        bais.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        String validacionXml="";
        if(vec!=null && vec.hasEvents()){
            for(ValidationEvent ve:vec.getEvents()){
                validacionXml += ve.getMessage();
            }
        }else{
            validacionXml += ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

    }
```

part of the xsd is:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Indicador_Prueba">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="1"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
```

It works perfect, it validates everything. The problem is when it launches this enumeration Exception, it says something like:

> cvc-enumeration-valid: Value ''{0}'' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration ''{1}''. It must be a value from the enumeration

Is it possible to get the element that is throwing the exception? at least get the element type?

thanks in an advance to everyone!

Comment: You've pruned too much.  Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: maybe this post can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295028/how-to-get-validation-events-with-jaxb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, instead of using a ValidationEventCollector which gets the error but in a low level, I used a Validator and to control the errors used an error handler. Now I get the cvc-enumeration-valid error and get which type throwed it.
Here is an example:

```
url = FILE.class.getResource("xsd/file.xsd");
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        schema = sf.newSchema(xsdUrl);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        final List<SAXParseException> exceptions = new LinkedList<SAXParseException>();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                exceptions.add(exception);
            }

            public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                exceptions.add(exception);
            }
        });

        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(peticion.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        //validate the xml against the xsd
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(bais));
        if(!exceptions.isEmpty()){
            for(SAXParseException ex:exceptions){
                validacionXml += ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Once you launch the validate method the errorHandler archives all the errors, fatal errors, or warnings if you want getting, in my case, the type that launches the error.

Thanks to everyone