# How to resolve cvc-pattern-valid: Value '' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern problem

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

I am trying to read `xsd` file and its throwing below `exception`:

```
cvc-pattern-valid: Value '' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[1-2][0-9]{3,3}(((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))((0[1-9])|([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]([0-5][0-9](\.[0-9]{1,4})?)?)?)?)?)?([+\-](0[0-9]|1[0-3])([0-5][0-9]))?' for type '#AnonType_valueTS'.

    final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans/src/mySchema.xsd"));
      final Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
      final StreamSource xmlFile = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("utf-8")));
      validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

This `validator.validate`(xmlFile) part is throwing `exception`.

Any Idea? Appreciate your kind help here.

and I have already looked in to below:
[Value is not facet-valid with respect to pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622869/cvc-pattern-valid-value-a-is-not-facet-valid-with-respect-to-pattern-a-za)

[Validating xml. Get the element name that throws cvc-enumeration-valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717674/validating-xml-get-the-element-name-that-throws-cvc-enumeration-valid)

Comment: Can't tell why your XML source is invalid without seeing the schema and source document. But a little point about your code: if you have XML source in a string xmlStr, it's best to do `new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr))` rather than going via a byte array - with your way, you run the risk of encoding problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XSD specifies that `Value` must match a specified regular expression that does not allow an empty string.

Either change `Value` to be a non-empty value that conforms to the XSD's regex, or change the regex to allow an empty string.